# A dire-needing country

Tags: single-word-requests

> The cure could find its way in **dire-needing** USK? (USK is a
>   fictional country)

I am looking for a synonym to the word (dire-needing). I am skeptical about it being acceptable to say the least.

Comment: Find its way 'in' USK, or 'to' USK? Is the cure potentially becoming available (to) or potentially finding success (in) in USK?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a synonym for the equivalent of 'desperate', or perhaps 'desperately needy'?

Comment: could find its way to USK. Thanks @CotyJohnathanSaxman

Answer (score 2):

> The cure could find its way to USK, where it is **urgently** needed.

Your original construction, 'dire-needing,' appears to be mistaken. 'Direly-needing' or 'direly-needy' would be appropriate alternatives. 'Needing' is a present-participle verb, so it takes an adverb as a modifier. The adjective 'dire' can be construed as an adverb in the form 'direly.'

Other possible replacements for dire/direly are urgently, alarmingly, critically, desperately, etc. Plugging any of those words into a thesaurus will yield more results.

Answer (score 1):

If a single word is sought, I would proffer *needy*.

Alternatives would include stronger words for "poor", such as *indigent*, *destitute*  and *penurious*. I think the first two of these actually capture the essence nicely, and include a connotation of being in dire need, whereas the third (to me) just describes a state of extreme poverty.

Comment: The context of the OP's query sentence (plus his/her subsequent clarification) suggests a medical emergency, not an economic one. However, 'needy' has a broad enough range of connotations to enable it to cover both contingencies.

Comment: @ErikKowal Often, the biggest obstacle to getting adequate medical help during a health-crisis is a lack of financial resources and economic development in the afflicted region. Poverty breeds disease, worsens its impact, and delays its eradication. But your point is well-taken. In any case, various alternatives were offered for the OP to choose from.